# Add an observed qualifier to an observer method in CDI portable extension

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I use the following code in a portable CDI extension to add a "default" qualifier to an observer method declaration.

```
void processObserverMethod(@Observes ProcessObserverMethod<? extends ConfigurableEvent<?>, ?> observerMethod) {
    Set<Annotation> qualifiers = observerMethod.getObserverMethod().getObservedQualifiers();
    if (!qualifiers.contains(new AnnotationLiteral<Special>() {})) {
        qualifiers.add(new AnnotationLiteral<Normal>() {});
    }
```

The goal is, having two mutually exclusive qualifiers `Normal` and `Special` to avoid declaring the `Normal` one at each observer declaration.

The code works in Weld 1.1 but not in 2.0. I've opened a [bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-1439!) but Weld guys told me that this is not supported by CDI specs.

Does anyone know an alternative way to achieve the same result?

Comment: I'm bit confused by what you want to accomplish with these qualifiers. One possible way would be to keep a list of the qualifiers in the payload. You'd have to check both places though, but it would work.

Comment: I think an interceptor would work here as well. What was the weld issue #?.  NM I see it.  Yes, this is now blocked from rewriting observer methods in CDI 1.1 spec.

Comment: @LightGuard: the goal is to avoid executing observers methods that don't declare `Special` when a `Special` qualified event is fired without explicitly declaring the method to observe only `Normal` events. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @JohnAment: I actually used a combination of the two, with qualifiers kept in the event itself and an interceptor that suppress execution of Normal methods when a Special event is fired. Thanks for your suggestions.